# Norm of a functional is a norm on a v.s. $X^{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that $\| \cdot \|_{X^{*}}$ is indeed a norm on $X^{*}$, the space of bounded linear functionals on a normed space $(X, \| \cdot \| )$.

---

I am not sure what to do in this. I do know that we probably have to check the conditions from the norm definition.

So the definition of $||\cdot||_{X^{*}}$ is: Let $(X ||\cdot ||)$ be a normed v.s. For a continuous linear functional $f\in X^{*}$, its norm is $$||f||_{X^{*}}=\inf \{C>0: |f(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}$$ I think it is quite trivial that $||f||_{X^{*}} \geq 0$ because we are working with positive and nonnegative values only.

Showing $f=0 \iff ||f||_{X^{*}}=0$ and the rest of the conditions of a norm seem quite difficult...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First condition**: $f=0\Longleftrightarrow ||f||_{X^*} = 0$

Assume that $f=0$. As $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in X$, we have $|f(x)| = 0$ for all $x$. Thus $||f||_{X^*} = \inf\{C>0\ :\ 0\leq C||x||,\ \forall x\in X\}$, which gives you $||f||_{X^*}=0$.

Assume that $||f||_{X^*}=0$. I want to prove that $f$ is the zero-functional, i.e. that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in X$, so pick one such $x$. By definition of $||f||_{X^*}$, there is a sequence $C_n>0$ of numbers, such that $C_n\rightarrow 0$, and such that $|f(x)|\leq C_n||x||$. Since $|f(x)|$ is independent of $n$ and non-negative, this shows that $|f(x)| = 0$, or $f(x) = 0$.

**Second condition**: $||cf||_{X^*} = |c|\cdot||f||_{X^*}$

We have
\begin{align*}
||cf||_{X^*} &= \inf \{C>0: |(cf)(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= \inf \{C>0: |cf(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= \inf \{C>0: |c|\cdot |f(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= \inf \{C>0: |f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{|c|} ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= |c|\cdot \inf \{C>0: |f(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= |c|\cdot ||f||_{X^*}
\end{align*}

**Third condition**: $||f+g||_{X^*}\leq ||f||_{X^*} + ||g||_{X^*}$

We have
\begin{align*}
||f+g||_{X^*} &= \inf \{C>0: |(f+g)(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= \inf \{C>0: |f(x)+g(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&\leq \inf \{C>0: |f(x)|+|g(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&\leq \inf \{C>0: |f(x)|\leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}+\inf \{C>0: |g(x)| \leq C ||x||, \, \, \forall x \in X \}\\
&= ||f||_{X^*} + ||g||_{X^*}
\end{align*}
In the first inequality, I use the triangle inequality: When I replace $|f(x)+g(x)|$ by the larger quantity $|f(x)|+|g(x)|$, the infimum becomes larger. In the second inequality, I use that if $|f(x)|\leq C_f||x||$ and $|g(x)|\leq C_g||x||$ for all $x$ and constants $C_f$ and $C_g$, then also $|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq (C_f+C_g)||x||$ for all $x$, i.e. the sum of the infimums will be at least as large as the infimum of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that
$$
\|f\|_{X^*} = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}.
$$
With this characterization the proof becomes easier.

Answer (score 1):

If $f=0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ and 
$\{C>0:~|f(x)|\leq C\|x\| ~\forall x\}=(0,+\infty)$, so $\|f\|=\inf(0,+\infty)=0.$ If $\|f\|=0$, then there is a sequence $(C_n)$ in $\{C>0:~|f(x)|\leq C\|x\| ~~\forall x\}$ that converges to $0$. So, for $x\in X$ we have for all $n$ that $|f(x)|\leq C_n\|x\|\rightarrow 0$, and therefore $|f(x)|=0$, i.e. $f(x)=0$.

For $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\|\lambda f\|=\inf\{C>0:~|\lambda f(x)|\leq C\|x\| ~~\forall x\}=
\inf\Big\{C>0:~| f(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|\lambda|}~\|x\| ~~\forall x\Big\}$$
$$=|\lambda|~\inf\Big\{\frac{C}{|\lambda|}>0:~| f(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|\lambda|}~\|x\| ~~\forall x\Big\}=|\lambda| ~\| f\|.$$

For the triangle inequality, let $C(f)=\{C>0:~|f(x)|\leq C\|x\| ~~\forall x\}$, so $C(f)+C(g)\subset C(f+g)$: indeed, if 
$C_1\in C(f),~C_2\in C(g)$ then $C_1+C_2\in C(f+g)$, since 
$$|(f+g)(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq C_1\|x\|+C_2\|x\|=(C_1+C_2)\|x\|~~\forall x\in X.$$
So $$\|f+g\|=\inf C(f+g)\leq \inf(C(f)+C(g))=\inf C(f)+\inf C(g)=\|f\|+\|g\|.$$

Note. Maybe you'd like to edit your post: $||f(x)$ should be $|f(x)|.$